# C#: Listbox Contextmenu for Listboxitems (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, contextmenu, listboxitem

i want for my Listbox in WPF a contextmenu.
I did it with a contextmenu for the whole listbox, but you can richt-click to get the contextmenu even if you don't click on a item.

I found something at google, but this didn't work out.

I tried something like this:

```
<ListBox Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}" Click="MenuItemName_Click"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Capital}"  Click="MenuItemCapital_Click"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Population}" Click="MenuItemPopulation_Click"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I tried it with a textblock like in the example, with other elements like in other tutorials, i tired it without and many other things- but nothing worked. No contextmenu for my listbox items :(

later i tried something like this:

```
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <ListBoxItem>
             <ListBoxItem.ContextMenu>
                 <ContextMenu>
                     <MenuItem/>
                 </ContextMenu>
             </ListBoxItem.ContextMenu>
         </ListBoxItem>
     </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

But it didn't work too.

Can someone give me a hint/working example :)?

thank you

Comment: What exactly doesn't work ? You need to be more specific... Did you check the output window in VS for binding errors ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would set the `ContextMenu` in the `ListBoxItem`'s style, rather than in the `DataTemplate`:

```
<ListBox Name="simpleListBox"
         ItemsSource="{Binding SimpleList}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        ...
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: @Thomas, I binding the Command with a RelayCommand in MenuItem, but the RalayCommand never is called.

Comment: @SubmarineX, can you see any binding errors in the output window? If you see something like "Cannot find governing FrameworkElement...", have a look at [this solution](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque thank u, now I have got it. Because the datacontext of the ListBoxItem is not the datacontext of the ListBox, so I binding the command to ListBoxItem's datacontext, then through messager notify the listbox's datacontext. And later I will see your solution.